# print binary tree using classes

Tags: python, class

I've created 2 functions for creating a binary tree and adding a node using recursion:

Creating the root:

```
def create_node(number = None):
    return {"number": number, "right": None, "left":None}
```

Adding a node using recursion:

```
def insert(number, pointer):
    pointer_number=pointer["number"]
    if pointer_number is None:
        pointer["number"]=number
    elif number > pointer_number:
        if pointer["right"] is None:
            pointer["right"] = create_node(number) 
        else:
            insert(number, pointer["right"])
    else:
        if pointer["left"] is None:
            pointer["left"] = create_node(number)
        else:
            insert (number, pointer["left"])
```

Recently I started working with classes and I'm still trying to get a hold of this. What Im trying to do is to create the same logic by using a class called Node:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number=number
        self.right=None
        self.lef=None

    def add_node(self,number):
        if number < self.number:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = __init__(number)
            else:
                self.left = self.left.add_node(number)
        if number > self.number:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = __init__(number)
            else:
                self.right = self.right.add_node(number)

    def see_tree(self):
        print(self.number)
```

The problem I'm facing is the add_node function. When I'm trying to run it i get this error:

> 'Node' object has no attribute 'left'

Any thoughts on how to make this work? Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typo in your code: `self.lef = None` in `__init__`. I think you meant `self.left = None`